# Total sum from a set (logic)

Tags: ios, algorithm, optimization, logic, brute-force

I have a logic problem for an iOS app but I don't want to solve it using brute-force.

I have a set of integers, the values are not unique:

```
[3,4,1,7,1,2,5,6,3,4........]
```

How can I get a subset from it with these 3 conditions:

- I can only pick a defined amount of values.
- The sum of the picked elements are equal to a value.
- The selection must be random, so if there's more than one solution to the value, it will not always return the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read that [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656789/find-2-numbers-in-an-unsorted-array-equal-to-a-given-sum)?

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070359/finding-three-elements-in-an-array-whose-sum-is-closest-to-an-given-number

Comment: Yea, both related question do not fit this one because (1) number of items is unlimited here. (2) None asks for a random choice if multiple solutions exist.

Comment: As Amit points out in his answer the problem is NP-Complete.  You didn't mention an unlimited number of items in your question though - this means you can't sort the items

Comment: The number of items is limited, but the solution needs to be random if there are more than one option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [subset sum proble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)m, it is a known NP-Complete problem, and thus there is no known efficient (polynomial) solution to it.

**However**, if you are dealing with only relatively low integers - there is a *pseudo polynomial* time solution using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

The idea is to build a matrix bottom-up that follows the next recursive formulas:

```
D(x,i) = false   x<0
D(0,i) = true
D(x,0) = false   x != 0
D(x,i) = D(x,i-1) OR D(x-arr[i],i-1)
```

The idea is to mimic an exhaustive search - at each point you "guess" if the element is chosen or not.

To get the actual subset, you need to trace back your matrix. You iterate from `D(SUM,n)`, (assuming the value is true) - you do the following (after the matrix is already filled up):

```
if D(x-arr[i-1],i-1) == true:
    add arr[i] to the set
    modify x <- x - arr[i-1]
    modify i <- i-1
else // that means D(x,i-1) must be true
    just modify i <- i-1
```

To get a random subset at each time, if both `D(x-arr[i-1],i-1) == true` AND `D(x,i-1) == true` choose randomly which course of action to take.

Python Code (If you don't know python read it as pseudo-code, it is very easy to follow).

```
arr = [1,2,4,5]
n = len(arr)
SUM = 6
#pre processing:
D = [[True] * (n+1)]
for x in range(1,SUM+1):
    D.append([False]*(n+1))
#DP solution to populate D:
for x in range(1,SUM+1):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        D[x][i] = D[x][i-1]
        if x >= arr[i-1]:
            D[x][i] = D[x][i] or D[x-arr[i-1]][i-1]
print D

#get a random solution:

if D[SUM][n] == False:
    print 'no solution'
else:
    sol = []
    x = SUM
    i = n
    while x != 0:
        possibleVals = []
        if D[x][i-1] == True:
            possibleVals.append(x)
        if x >= arr[i-1] and D[x-arr[i-1]][i-1] == True:
            possibleVals.append(x-arr[i-1])
        #by here possibleVals contains 1/2 solutions, depending on how many choices we have.
        #chose randomly one of them
        from random import randint
        r = possibleVals[randint(0,len(possibleVals)-1)]
        #if decided to add element:
        if r != x:
            sol.append(x-r)
        #modify i and x accordingly
        x = r
        i = i-1
    print sol
```

**P.S.**

The above give you random choice, but NOT with uniform distribution of the permutations.

To achieve uniform distribution, you need to **count** the number of possible choices to build each number.

The formulas will be:

```
D(x,i) = 0 x<0
D(0,i) = 1
D(x,0) = 0   x != 0
D(x,i) = D(x,i-1) + D(x-arr[i],i-1)
```

And when generating the permutation, you do the same logic, but you decide to add the element `i` in probability `D(x-arr[i],i-1) / D(x,i)`

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you very much for your help, do you know if there's any way to limit the solution only to a certain amount of values? For example, assuming there will always be an answer, get only a solution with X values

Comment: @mtet88 yes, add a dimension with number of values used, and modify the recursivr formula to `D(x,i,j) = D(x-arr[i],i-1,j-1) OR D(x,i-1,j)`, and change stop clauses accordingly so only `D(0,i,0) = true`. Similar solution for counting number of subsets.

Comment: I'm really really sorry being this annoying, I'm completely lost... With this I can create the new matrix (cube in this case) with this logic: D(x,i,j) = 0 x<0 || j<0
D(0,i,0) = 1
D(x,0,j) = 0   x != 0 && j!=0
D(x,i,j) = D(x-arr[i],i-1,j-1) OR D(x,i-1,j) but what next? the method that actually gets the solution completely changes