# Minimum Complexity of two lists element summation comparison

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have a question in algorithm design about arrays, which should be implement in C language.
Suppose that we have an array which has n elements. For simplicity n is power of '2' like `1, 2, 4, 8, 16 , etc`. I want to separate this to 2 parts with `(n/2)` elements. Condition of separating is `lowest absolute difference between sum of all elements in two arrays` for example if I have this array `(9,2,5,3,6,1,4,7)` it will be separate to these arrays `(9,5,1,3)` and `(6,7,4,2)` . summation of first array's elements is `18` and the summation of second array's elements is `19` and the difference is 1 and these two arrays are the answer but two arrays like `(9,5,4,2)` and `(7,6,3,1)` isn't the answer because the difference of element summation is `4` and we have found `1` . so `4` isn't the minimum difference. How to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: PS, why the restriction of `n` be a power of 2? To have two subarrays of the exact same size, you just need `n` to be even, and not the much stronger assumption of it being power of 2.

Comment: @amit I know this buddy . but I think in the next steps it will separate it to another pieces so it needs an n in this condition

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597180/divide-an-array-into-two-sets-with-minimal-difference

Comment: @therealprashant Not exactly a dupe, since there is an extra restriction here on the cardinality of the two subsets (same size)

Comment: Actually I should have said refer <link> instead of duplicate <link>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is unfortunately [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

However, since your numbers are integers, if they are relatively low, there is a pseudo polynomial `O(W*n^2)`  solution using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) (where `W` is sum of all elements).

The idea is to create the DP matrix of size `(W/2+1)*(n+1)*(n/2+1)`, based on the following recursive formula:

```
D(0,i,0) = true
D(0,i,k) = false     k != 0
D(x,i,k) = false     x < 0
D(x,0,k) = false     x > 0
D(x,i,0) = false     x > 0
D(x,i,k) = D(x,i-1,k) OR D(x-arr[i], i-1,k-1)
```

The above gives a 3d matrix, where each entry `D(x,i,k)` says if there is a subset containing exactly `k` elements, that sums to `x`, and uses the first `i` elements as candidates.

Once you have this matrix, you just need to find the highest `x` (that is smaller than SUM/2) such that `D(x,n,n/2) = true`

Later, you can get the relevant subset by going back on the table and "retracing" your choices at each step. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29512660/572670) deals with how it is done on a very similar problem.

---

For small sets, there is also the alternative of a naive brute force solution, which basically splits the array to all possible halves (`(2n)!/(n!*n!)` of those), and picks the best one out of them.