# F# - Return a value from for .. do

Tags: loops, f#, iteration, big-o

I have a (random) set of numbers and I want to decide for any given number, whether the number is a composite one (meaning it can be created by two other numbers in the same given set).
*Mathematical definition of my function:*

[image]

**Current code:**

```
let task1 (M : seq<'T>, r : 'T) : bool =
    if not(Seq.exists((=) r) M) then
        failwith "nope!"
    else
        for s in M do
            for t in M do
                if s + t = r then
                    true         // error
        false
```

**Issue:**
I cannot return a boolean result from my iteration, when the element `r` has been 'found' as sum of the two elements `s` and `t`.

---

How could I solve the given problem as efficiently as possible?

*If somebody finds an algorithm with a **total** run-time smaller than O(n²), then it is also fine by me.


[all called methods must also be faster than O(n²)]*

Comment: Is this by chance homework? When someone ask for an algorithm with a limit on big O I just have to ask. O(n2) is obvious for this question.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Well, it was a task, which could come up in a later exam and I am currently trying to write it in F# ;) Thank you for your second comment, Sir - I realize I have forgotten a `not`

Comment: In this case, use Seq.find instead of cycles

Comment: and no need to annotate the type, you can simply specify `inline`

Comment: @FoggyFinder: `Seq.find` is very neat, but I will have a look at its performance...

Comment: @Unknown6656 `Seq.find` and `Seq.exists` are O(n).

Comment: Did they say `composite` in the question? A composite number is made by multiplying and you are using adding. I asked because in searching for existing code I realized that composite was an invalid keyword to use.

Comment: Of interest: [Find 2 numbers in an unsorted array equal to a given sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656789/find-2-numbers-in-an-unsorted-array-equal-to-a-given-sum)

Comment: Of interest: [Find a pair of elements from an array whose sum equals a given number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number)

Comment: Of interest: [Given an array A and a number x, check for pair in A with sum as x](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/)

Comment: Of interest: [Find two numbers in an array whose sum is x](http://www.cs.uml.edu/~jlu1/doc/codes/findSum.html) This one uses hashing and says O(n).

Comment: @GuyCoder I wonder if the hash version will really be faster, even if its typical-case complexity is O(n). Hashing isn't O(n) in worst-case scenarios... and won't the required relative amount of padding in the hashtable be logarithmic in the end, making the trick moot? I must admit though, I'm not quite sure I'm getting the statistics right. Curious what a benchmark would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you don't want to use loops to implement complicated iterations / recursive functions in F#. That's what tail recursive functions are good for.

To get the computational complexity below O(n²), how about this: consider the set of candidate summands, which is the complete set of numbers at first. Now look at the sum of the largest and smallest number in this set. If this sum is larger than the target number, the largest number won't sum to the target number with anything. The same goes the other way around.

Keep dropping the smallest or largest number from the set of candidates until either the set is empty or a match has been found.

The code could look like this:

```
let rec f M x =
    if Set.isEmpty M then false else
    let biggest, smallest = Set.maxElement M, Set.minElement M
    let sum = biggest + smallest
    if   sum > x then f (Set.remove biggest M)  x
    elif sum < x then f (Set.remove smallest M) x
    elif sum = x then true
    else failwith "Encountered failure to compare numbers / NaN"
```

When I look at the mathematical definition, it doesn't seem to be a requirement that the target number is in the set. But if this matters, just check beforehand:

```
let fChecked M x =
    if Set.contains x M then f M x
    else invalidArg "x" "Target number is not contained in set."
```

Tom make this generic over the comparable type, the function could be marked `inline`.

Set operations are O(log n), we go over the whole thing once, multiplying O(n), making the total complexity **O(n log n)** (where n is the number of elements in the set).

---

**Effective speed version**

If it's about actual speed rather than "just" the computational complexity, arrays are probably faster than immutable sets. Here's a version that uses array indices:

```
/// Version where M is types as an unsorted array we're allowed to sort
let f M x =
    Array.sortInPlace M
    let rec iter iLow iHigh =
        if iLow > iHigh then false else
        let sum = M.[iLow] + M.[iHigh]
        if   sum > x then iter iLow (iHigh - 1)
        elif sum < x then iter (iLow + 1) iHigh
        elif sum = x then true
        else failwith "Encountered failure to compare numbers / NaN"
    iter 0 (M.Length - 1)
```

Note that we could pre-sort the array if the same set is used repeatedly, bringing down the complexity for each call on the same set down to **O(n)**.

Comment: I very much like this solution, though I think I prefer @TheInnerLight's one due to its simplicity...., but I think that yours has more performance :)

Comment: @Unknown6656 Well, you asked for computational complexity of less than O(n²). I figured that would be the more interesting exercise. :P

Comment: So right you are, Sir. I will however tomorrow accept an answer (not yet), to give others the chance of posting other 'exercises' ;)

Comment: @GuyCoder It seems it could be made simpler after all, and your mention of balanced trees gave me the idea. The F# Set type is based on balanced trees internally and supports finding the largest/smallest elements in O(log n). I edited the answer, the function is now a good bit shorter and should be producing the same result. Maybe I'll add notes about an array/speedy version again? hm. Glad you like the answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't do what you're trying to do because F# is a language that uses expressions rather than statements.  F# expressions always evaluate to a value (although that value might be unit: `()`).

The code you originally posted doesn't compile because something of type `unit` is expected, that's because your `if/then` expression has no `else` branch.  Consider the following:

```
let a = if x > 5 then 10
```

This code will produce a compiler error, that's obvious because we haven't specified what the integer value of `a` might be if `x` is not greater than 5.

Of course, this code will compile:

```
let a = if x > 5 then 10 else 5
```

If you provide and `if` without an `else`, the F# compiler will assume the type is unit so this is also valid code:

```
let a = if x > 5 then ()
```

This is because both cases still just return `unit`, there is no type mismatch.

Because F# uses expressions, everything has to be bindable to a value.

---

Anyway, you can solve this by using nested `Seq.exists` statements, this way you can check every combination of values.

```
let inline task1 items r =
    items |> Seq.exists (fun s ->
        items |> Seq.exists(fun t -> s + t = r))
```

I've changed some of your naming conventions (it's idiomatic for F# function parameters to be camelCased) and have made your function `inline` so it will work on any type that supports addition.