# Most efficient algorithm for finding a subset of a sorted array having a given sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, big-o

So I've been reading posts like [Finding three elements in an array whose sum is closest to a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070359/finding-three-elements-in-an-array-whose-sum-is-closest-to-an-given-number) and [Find a pair of elements from an array whose sum equals a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number), and it appears that almost all the questions are targeted towards pairs or triplets.

My question is, given an sorted array, a number **n**, and a sum **S**, is there a "universal" algorithm that returns **S** by checking and adding **n** numbers in the array? I know how to do pairs and triplets efficiently now, but I can't seem to find any algorithm relating to **n>3**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Your question's title is misleading.  "the sum of X numbers" can of course be computed in O(X) time.

Comment: Sorry, I am not exactly sure how to work it. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8926458/1254880

Comment: How about "[Most efficient algorithm for] finding a subset of a sorted array having a given sum" (first part in brackets because it's not really necessary).  Also both questions you linked to word it properly!

Answer (score 0):

Let MAX be size of the array.  Consider all binary numbers of MAX digits; let a "1" for digit j mean "the jth number is included in sum S," and a 0 for digit j mean that it isn't.

There are then 2^MAX possible solutions.  You can do a linear search.  Not so efficient.

You can instead do this for pruning:

```
findSolution (Array, MAX, n, S, SolutionSoFar, j) is
  if SolutionSoFar has n digits set to 1
    if the sum it represents == S
       return SolutionSoFar -- we win
    else
       return false

  if (result = findSolution (Array, MAX, n, S, SolutionSoFar with jth set to 1, j+1))
     return result 
  else if (result = findSolution (Array, MAX, n, S, SolutionSoFar with jth set to 0, j+1))
     return result
  else
     return false


findSolution (Array, MAX, n, S, a binary number of MAX digits all 0's, 0)
```

O-notation will still show this as exponential, but it's better.

You could now put more intelligence into this:  throw out any solution in which an item > S-(n-1) (assuming all items are of size at least 1).  Prefer to add things close to average of (S-(sum so far))/(items left to add).

Will have to think further if there is a better-than-exponential algorithm, or if we can prove there is not.